How to play files generated by Gstreamer multifilesink?
Use below command to successfully continuously saving frame files.
gst-launch-1.0 pulsevideosrc ! vaapipostproc ! vaapiencode_h264 ! mpegtsmux ! multifilesink location = multisrc/frame%d.ts

saved files
ls -la
total 11260
drwxr-xr-x  2 dev3lx dev3lx 303104 May 15 10:28 .
drwx------ 23 dev3lx dev3lx   4096 May 15 11:35 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    21056 May 15 10:27 frame0.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     5640 May 15 10:28 frame100.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     7332 May 15 10:28 frame101.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     2632 May 15 10:28 frame102.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     4700 May 15 10:28 frame103.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     6016 May 15 10:28 frame104.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     7708 May 15 10:28 frame105.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     2820 May 15 10:28 frame106.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     4888 May 15 10:28 frame107.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     6392 May 15 10:28 frame108.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     7332 May 15 10:28 frame109.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     9964 May 15 10:27 frame10.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     3008 May 15 10:28 frame110.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     4888 May 15 10:28 frame111.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     5640 May 15 10:28 frame112.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     7708 May 15 10:28 frame113.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     2820 May 15 10:28 frame114.ts
...

But I don't know how to play the saved files. What I tried is use VLC player and select all the saved files, but it doesn't work. I also tried playing individual saved file, however majority file cannot be played. Can you advise how to play them?

gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location="multisrc/frame%d.ts" ! tsdemux ! h264parse ! vaapih264dec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink


Can you also advise how to merge these files to one mp4 format file?

You may try: gst-launch-1.0 -e multifilesrc location="multisrc/frame%d.ts" ! tsdemux ! h264parse ! qtmux ! filesink location=test.mp4
